# How to solve the ODE eq system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In EVAN's textbook PDE: P100- Example 1,

If $$x'_1(s)=-x_2(s)$$
$$x'_2(s)=x_1(s)$$

That is, $$ \begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\\dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

> The answer is $x_1(s)=x_0\cos s$ and $x_2(s)=x_0 \sin s$

I feel that $x_0$ is an initial condition. In the equation, we can get the eigenvalue of the matrix $\lambda_1=i$ and $\lambda_2=-i$.

So I get the solution is
$x(s)=c_1 v_1 e^{is}+c_2v_2 e^{-is}$
where $v_1=(i, 1)^T$ and $v_2=(i, -1)^T$. Suppose $x_0=(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}$ so that $(x_1, x_2)=(x_0\cos s, x_0 \sin s)$.

But I do not get the answer. What is wrong?

Comment: Check your trigonometric for $x_1$ and $x_2$ do not satisfy your simultaneous ODE.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc No.. Sorry for the mistake. That is $x_2'=x_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X_1'=-X_2 \implies X_1''=-X_2'=-X_1 \implies \frac{d^2X_1}{ds^2}=-X_1$$ $$\implies X_1=A \sin s+ B \cos s`...(1)$$
D.w.r.t. $s$ we get $$X_2'= X_1 \implies X_2'=A \sin s+ B \cos s \implies X_2= -A \cos s +B \sin s ...(2)$$

Finally (1) and (2) are required solutions.

Comment: No.. Sorry for the mistake. That is $x_2'=x_1$.

Comment: OK then see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As given, the solution is indeed a solution to the ODE, but it is not the most general. Maybe you forgot some given initial condition(s)…

(By the way $x_1''(s)=-x_1(s)\implies x_1(s)=c_c\cos(s)+c_s\sin s$.)